# Use the same SVG Geometry on different controls by trigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

So I have this style

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
        x:Key="BlueRedToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Path Data="{StaticResource Cross}" Fill="White"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Path Data="{StaticResource Check}" Fill="White"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Basically, a toggle button, when it's checked, it changes its content to an svg of a check, when it's not it gets a cross instead. I have multiple of these in my window xaml, but, when I run the program, only one of them gets the svg. If I check multiple buttons the image appears only in the most recently clicked.

How can I make it so every button gets its content modified with my svg using triggers? (if there's even a way or if it's correct to do so).

I notice that this only happens with the svgs, if I assign the content as a string every button gets their string and reacts to changes correctly.

This is the svg data that I'm using, I don't know if it has something to do with it.

````xml
<PathGeometry x:Key="Check" Figures="m10 15.586-3.293-3.293-1.414 1.414L10 18.414l9.707-9.707-1.414-1.414z"/>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the geometry like this creates a single static resource instance, which is polled every time when a reference to it is resolved. To avoid visual tree cycles and other UI mess-ups, WPF won't let you effectively use the same instance in different nodes of the visual tree. To overcome this behavior, you can set [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute)
to `False`, which will result in generating a new geometry instance when some new button needs one. I have used this solution for similar corner case scenarios, but it comes with certain shortcomings when there is very extensive usage of this resource.

I guess that the remark from [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) renders this reply as incorrect. I would suggest that you try setting `ContentTemplate` instead of `Content` as then you are guaranteed to have a new sub-tree, without the need of making shenanigans with Shared.

Comment: Geometries are no Visuals, and hence no elements of a visual tree. In contrast to UI elements, a single Geometry can be re-used in several places, e.g. as the Data of different Path elements. You may however need to set x:Shared on the Style.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. Then, I guess that the style and its setters are static, which will result in having a static Path in the Setter.Value, which must be the problem.

Comment: Set `x:Shared="False"` on the Style.

Comment: Yeah, `x:Shared="False"` did the trick, thanks a lot!